# LMR16030 voltage regulator pin configuration

Tags: voltage-regulator, soldering, pins, configuration

I just bought a HSOIC-8 LMR16030 and have tried to plugged it in my circuit but didn't manage to make it work. I'm thinking this might be due to me misunderstanding the pin configuration. What are the pin numbers in this picture?

[image: LMR16030 chip]

Updated: Zoomed image (2x original dimensions on each side)

[image: LMR16030 chip - larger image]

Comment: What does the [dataheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmr16030.pdf) say?

Comment: Wow, this is one of the worst framed pictures I have seen in a while.

Comment: ...the most pointless picture ever taken?

Comment: Took this with my iPhone so couldn't get much closer as it got quite blurry. There should be a black dot next to pin one according to the datasheet, but I can't see any, all there is is text and a golden line.

Comment: Pin 1 is at the bottom left of the photo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What are the pin numbers in this picture?

In that image, pin 1 is bottom left, pin 8 is top left

Although your physical IC is missing the "dot" shown in some parts of the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmr16030.pdf), the thick white line seen in your photo, is another standard marking for the "pin 1 end".

Also this drawing from the datasheet shows another indicator:

[image: Package drawing from TI LMR16030 datasheet]

Based on the industry standard JEDEC MS-012, there can be an optional "chamfer" along the "pin 1 to pin 4" edge of this package - I have highlighted the relevant details in red on the drawing. I *think* I can see a darker line on your photo along that edge, which could indicate that the chamfer is present on your IC.